# workable Component Object Model for nim?

Tags: com, nim-lang

Since pyinstaller/cxfreeze can't release standalone executable file for win 7 and win 10, I want to port my python + win32com application (which read existing word doc and docx files, so only win32com can work) to nim. However, I only found khchen's winim and Tormund's fork. The first one says

> C:\Users\LOVLJIDY.nimble\pkgs\winim-1.2.0\winim\winapi.nim(5298, 8) Error: overloaded 'GetEnvironmentStrings' leads to ambiguous calls

the second one says

> C:\Users\LOVLJIDY.nimble\pkgs\winim-1.2.0\winim\com.nim(681, 11) Error: overloaded 'variantConverter' leads to ambiguous calls

I have reported the detail as https://github.com/khchen/winim/issues/10 , but it seems that winim is abandoned.

So is there any workable Component Object Model library for current nim?

Comment: Why not just submit a pull request to Tormund and fix it? Apparently all `variantConverter` have to be removed, and `fromVariant` can be used explicitly.